# In the public opinion, why was Voldemort considered the greatest dark wizard of all times, and not Grindelwald?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, gellert-grindelwald

In the books, it's established that Voldemort is seen as the greatest dark wizard of all time (well, at least the greatest until now) by the wizarding world.

Given the hints and facts about Grindelwald in the books, I was always a bit confused and now, after the films, I'm even more surprised by this. The common knowledge about both, in the timeframe of the books, includes facts that suggest Grindelwald being the greater dark wizard:

- Grindelwald managed to rule (at least in eastern Europe) for quite some time, Voldemort never ruled even the UK in the first war and only ruled for some months in the second.
- Grindelwald had his own concentration camp (Nurmengard). Voldemort used Azkaban for a similar purpose, but that's in the last book, well after his reputation was already established.
- Grindelwald's followers must have been numerous, given that he managed to rule parts of Europe and have his own concentration camp. You need quite a few people to run a country (or a prison). Voldemort's followers, for the most part, were his few Death Eaters and some outcasts like werewolfs. He is not portrayed as the charismatic leader people rally to (he *is* portrayed like this during his school time, but this couldn't have any impact on his reputation, because most wizards won't ever know that Tom Riddle and Voldemort are the same person).
- Grindelwald was a seer, and a very powerful one - he accurately predicted events 18 years in the future. Only Trelawney managed to do something similar, in her prophecy about Harry and Voldemort, albeit in a less precise manner. As far as we know, this branch of magic was simply off-limits to Voldemort.
- Voldemort was brought down for the first time because of his own miscalculations, whereas Grindelwald was beaten in a duel. Grindelwald had to be stopped by someone, while all that Voldemort needed to fall was his own ignorance.

Please keep in mind that I'm **not** asking who actually *is* the greater dark wizard. My question is purely about how the common opinion on that matter came to be. Therefore, all informations that are not known to wizardkind at large aren't important (that, for example, is why I'm not mentioning Voldemort having Horcruxes or Grindelwald mastering the Elder Wand - nearly nobody knows about this, so it's not important for the public opinion).

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate since this seems to be basically the same as the other question, albeit yours is much more fleshed out. If it's not you can edit to clarify the difference(s).

Comment: the other question was asked at a time when the crimes of grindelwald was not released, and consequently, the answers cannot reflect this movie (which is important for understanding Grindelwalds goals and methods) and thus not the current state of the Harry Potter - canon. therefore, i simply consider it obsolete in the light of new developements in the canon (although it pretty much is the same question).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MZpj.jpg

Comment: sacrificing my own reputation just for an answer reflecting the current state of canon? no, thanks.

Comment: The existing answer still looks good to me, I don't think the new movies change things *all* that much.  The point about Grindelwald being a seer is interesting and might form the kernel of a new question, I'm not sure whether he really is - seers don't remember their own prophecies, after all.  I don't think your last point stands up; nobody but Dumbledore knew that Voldemort's first death was caused by his own mistake, everybody else thinks it was some kind of divine intervention or something.